# How can I toggle whole div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, toggle, innerhtml

I have a done function from which i want to toggle my "temp" div

```
tasks.innerHTML += `<div id="temp">
        <span id="taskname">
        ${input.value}
        </span>
         
        <button class="done" onclick ="done()"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i></button>
        <button class="del" onclick="del(this)"><i class="fa-solid fa-times-circle"></i></button>
        
        </div>`;
```

```
function del(e) {
    e.parentNode.remove();      
}

function done() {
    var temp = document.getElementById("temp");
    temp.classList.toggle('completed');      
}
```

In above code del function is working perfectly but done function is not it only toggles the first div created by innerhtml

[To Do List web App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axyQx.png)

Here if I click check button of Task 3 or Task 4 or Task 2 it will only affect the first div i.e. Task 2 here.

I tried to do it in the similar way I did del() function by using "this"

```
<button class="done" onclick ="done(this)"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i></button>
```

```
function done(e) {
    e.classList.toggle('completed');      
}
```

But it only toggles the particular check button as shown in image
[To Do List Web App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reS1j.png)

I want to toggle the whole division of task so that i can strikethrough the text of particular task using css by clicking particular check button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to add parentNode.

```
function done(e) {
    e.parentNode.classList.toggle('completed');     
};

onClick="done(this)"
```

Comment: Thanks alot actually I am new to javascript so i was just stuck on this step wasted my day on it but also got to learn new things in JS.